# Trying to upload a simple colab notebook to a webpage hosted by voila and mybinder, but the VBoxModel is not woking

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, mybinder, jupyter-widget

I'm the whole day trying to upload a simple deep learning model that predicts 3 thing in a web page using voila and mybinder. The problem is that I'm using the VBoxModel method to show the program, but its not working. error:

Error:

> Failed to load model class 'VBoxModel' from module '@jupyter-widgets/controls'
> Error: Module @jupyter-widgets/controls, version ^1.5.0 is not registered, however,         2.0.0 is
> at tn.loadClass.....

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm8h0.png)

The mybinder uses all this achieves to work, if you want to check the repository: https://github.com/ViniciusPrincipe/ProjetoIngles

[Archives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aM32.png)

The program is working perfectly, but when I build it on mybinder.org I'm always getting this problem

Comment: You link to the repository doesn't work. Did you mean https://github.com/ViniciusPrincipe/FinalProject2 or https://github.com/ViniciusPrincipe/InglesAgoraVai ? Guessing you mean the former since that has VBox?

Comment: I see the Voila link at https://github.com/ViniciusPrincipe/FinalProject2 now. I take it that specific notebook in the repo is the one with the issue? Wait. It works. What fixed things? Please update your OP to add that.